# DB index arrange. (sqlite)

Tags: database, sqlite, indexing

The problem that I have is index arrange probelm.

I have a DB file(sqlite) and but some little mistakes make this file`s index awful.

this file has records like below,

> index   data1   data2
>
> 1                a             ...
>
> 2                b             ...
>
> 50             c             ...
>
> 101          d             ...
>
> 200          e             ...

Because of this gap in index, index is increasing so fast....
So, I`d like to delete empty index, and stick all records continuously like below.

> index   data1   data2
>
> 1                a             ...
>
> 2                b             ...
>
> 3                c             ...
>
> 4                d             ...
>
> 5                e             ...

Anybody has a solution?

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Comment: @CL. Because of this, index is going to pass over, out of boundary so fast.

Comment: Over what? What boundary?